# How long can יוצא ונכנס be?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, time, inspection

In regards to kosher supervision, what is the largest single gap that a mashgiach can leave the premise and still be considered practicing יוצא ונכנס?

Comment: My maggid shiur in Yore Dea said: "It's called 'yotze v'nichnas', not 'nichnas v'yotze'. I.e. the mashgiach may only leave occasionally!"

Comment: The Rambam calls it Nichnas v yotzei. (Machalot Assurot 13:3 plus many more places there)

Answer (score 1):

From the Kashrus Organizations, it sounds like it depends on what product the Mashgiach is being יוצא ונכנס for. At least for the milking process, the time frame for the Mashgiach's entering/leaving [given by the OU](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/chalav-yisroel/) is

"In general, Poskim have ruled that yotzei v’nichnas supervision requires the mashgiach be present at the beginning of the milking, come in unannounced at least once in the middle, and come back at the conclusion of the milking. This applies to each milking session, typically lasting eight hours or so."

If you divide the 8 hour duration into beginning, middle, and end, then it's 4 hour intervals.

Comment: Assuming he comes *only* once in the middle, one of those gaps will likely be more than 4 hours.  Assume he comes somewhere in the middle 4 hours.  Now one gap is up to 6 hours and the other as little as 2.